# How can I reach chrome://plugins in Chrome 57 (or newer)?

Tags: google-chrome

In the past, Google Chrome allowed toggling of plugins (like enabling/disabling Flash) from the `chrome://plugins` URL. This page no longer exists (as of *Chrome 57.0.2987.98*).

What is the way to access Chrome plugins from this point onwards?

Comment: are you looking for chrome://extensions ?

Comment: No, plugins and extensions are quite different. I did come across [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/29/google-removes-plugin-controls-from-chrome/) though.

Comment: ah, then I think what you're looking for is under settings-->Privacy-->content settings-->plugins. Is that it?

Comment: Thanks. Seems like they've migrated most plugin features there.

Comment: I'm not seeing it in there now. Think they may have moved it again.

Comment: @BBaysinger, Steven's answer below is still accurate as of Chrome 62.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Chrome URL `chrome://plugins` was removed in Chrome version 57.

> [Chromium - Issue-615738: Deprecate chrome://plugins](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615738)
>
> Objective: Remove the chrome://plugins page, moving configuration for
>   the last remaining plugin, Flash Player, to it's own explicit place in
>   content settings (including an option, in settings, to disable).

Use `chrome://settings/content` to control when to display Flash content.

Use `chrome://components` to display Adobe Flash Player version.

Comment: In chrome 59 (and 57 probably too) this page is called (old //plugins/ with AdBlocker, YouTube HD etc.):
chrome://extensions/

'Flash' is not a plugin now. It's part of Chrome and you can change it on/off in settings.

Comment: this doesnt help how do i disable flash to disable pepperflash and use adobe flash instead